# use of apply function when you need to pass 'self' as argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a pandas dataframe df where one column is 'keywords' and another column is 'possible keywords', so that the first two rows look as follows:

```
df['keywords'][0] = 'traveling'
df['possible keywords'][0] = ['traveling', 'fishing','cooking']

df['keywords'][1] = 'fishing'
df['possible keywords'][0] = ['traveling', 'fishing','cooking']
```

Let's assume that every element in the df['possible keywords'] series contains the same list, with the same elements(['traveling', 'fishing','cooking']).

I want is to generate a third column where I include the 'possible keywords' that are not in the 'keyword' column, so that the corresponding rows look like this:

```
df['non keywords'][0] = ['fishing','cooking']
df['non keywords'][1] = ['traveling','cooking']
```

I was able to do so with the following piece of code:

```
def establish(X):
    my_list = ['traveling', 'fishing','cooking']
    for element in my_list:
        if element in X:
            my_list.remove(element)
            return my_list

data['non keywords'] = data['keywords'].apply(establish)
```

However, I had to include the value in column 'possible keywords' as 'my_list' in the establish function.

How can I do the same passing the value in 'possible keywords' as an argument to the establish function?

Here is the problem with what I have tried so far:

New version of establish function:

```
def establish(my_list,X):
    for element in my_list:
        if element in X:
            my_list.remove(element)
            return my_list

my_list = ['traveling', 'fishing','cooking']
data['non keywords'] = data['keywords'].apply(establish(my_list))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-21-859ebaa71600>", line 1, in <module>
    data['non keywords'] = data['keywords'].apply(establish(my_list))
TypeError: establish() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

If I instead try:

```
data['non keywords'] = data['keywords'].apply(establish(my_list,data['keywords']))
```

Here is the problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-22-ee891e061f5a>", line 1, in <module>
    data['non keywords'] =     data['original_keyword'].apply(establish(my_list,data['keywords']))
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2058, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1046, in pandas.lib.map_infer    (pandas\lib.c:56983)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) method expects as argument a function or other callable, which is exactly what you are passing in your first example when you pass `establish`. Internally, pandas calls the function you pass with each entry of your specified column in turn as argument.

Calling `establish(my_list)` will straight up not work because your function now takes 2 arguments.

Calling `establish(my_list,data['keywords'])` is a "valid" function call, but will return `None` and takes the wrong type of argument for its second parameter besides, because `establish` expects a single entry and not a column.  Once it returns `None`, that is what is actually passed to the `apply()` function, which is obviously not callable, and so pandas throws up.

One solution is to create a helper function that "pre-bakes" your first argument and takes the second argument as its only argument and then calls the `establish()` function with it, and that way you can pass that second function to the `apply()` method.  One handy way to do this is using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
import functools
my_list = ['traveling', 'fishing','cooking']
helper_func = functools.partial(establish, my_list) # note that helper_func is an actual function that you can call
data['non keywords'] = data['keywords'].apply(helper_func)
```

Comment: hi there, thanks a lot for the reply. I tried your approach but the result is that 'None' goes into every entry of data['non keywods']

Comment: hmm.. I just tried it with your example and got ['cooking'] for both rows of 'non keywords'.   The problem there is that your `establish()` method keeps modifying the same list in place (in your case, that would happen if the establish function is returning `None` regardless of the input).  Try changing the `establish()` method to do something like `return [elem for elem in my_list if elem != X]` or at least make sure to copy `my_list` instead of editing in-place.  Hope that helps

Comment: hi there, thanks a lot lemonhead, the syntax you suggested worked beautifully:                        def establish(x,my_list):
    return [elem for elem in my_list if elem not in x]. Also a note, I could use data['keywords'].apply(establish,args=(my_list,)) - I believe it works in the new pandas version - as an alternative to using functools